# Adding bleed to 3 of 4 sides on images with php

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

Im trying to add bleed to top,bottom and right sides of images what is written to PDF
The images is written correct to PDF but want to add bleed to 3 pages for cutting purpose

[image]

```
$sortert=$files->_fileListPath;
    sort ($sortert); // All jpg files is sorted
    $pdf = new Imagick($sortert);
    $pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
    $pdf->writeImages ($ordrepdf, true); //The jpg files is written to PDF
```

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering you require help with?

Comment: How to add bleed. example 3mm to the top,right and bottom of every image

Comment: @Martijn  I was able to accomplish what i needed by adding between the setImageFormat and writeImages . $pdf->setPage(1783, 2550, 0,8.9); ( width,height, horizontal. vertical values) There i set the page size to the pdf as 1783x2550 this page is equals the size i wanted and then i moved the image to the bleed matches the image above